# HSL random color applying it to a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am really new to jquery and am trying to have it such that the color generated for the word blink would always be a different color each time but can't figure out how to do so. Please look at my code below or check out the jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/schan01/2d8Rr/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>

        html{
            height:100%;
            overflow:hidden;
        }

        p{
            font-family: "Helvetica";
            font-size: 10px;
            float:left;
            margin:10px;

        }


        .box {
            width: 10px;
            height: 10px;    
            float:left;
            margin:10px;
        }



        .hovered{
            color: blue;

            -webkit-animation-name: blinker;
            -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
            -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
            -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;

            -moz-animation-name: blinker;
            -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
            -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
            -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;

            animation-name: blinker;
            animation-duration: 1s;
            animation-timing-function: linear;
            animation-iteration-count: infinite;

        }

        @-moz-keyframes blinker {  
        0% { opacity: 1.0; }
        50% { opacity: 0.0; }
        100% { opacity: 1.0; }
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes blinker {  
        0% { opacity: 1.0; }
        50% { opacity: 0.0; }
        100% { opacity: 1.0; }
        }

        @keyframes blinker {  
        0% { opacity: 1.0; }
        50% { opacity: 0.0; }
        100% { opacity: 1.0; }
        }




    </style>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        var g = 0;


        $(function() {

            for(var i=0; i<1000; i++){
                            $("body").append("<p>blink</p>");
                        }

            $("p").hover(function() {
                //hovered on
                $(this).addClass("hovered")({
                    "color":"hsl(" + g + ",100%,50%)"
                });

        });

    });

    </script>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Appreciate any help or advice given. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've missed the call for [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) after `.addClass()`

```
$(this).addClass("hovered").css({
    "color": "hsl(" + g + ",100%,50%)"
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2sRQ5/)

Comment: awesome:) thank you so much. quick qn, you also added this 

g = (g + 1) % 360;

what does this do? thanks

Comment: It just adds 1 to the value of `g` each time an element is hovered. The `% 360` "resets" `g` to zero if the max for `hue` (which goes from 0 to 360) is reached. If you hover enough elements in the fiddle you will see that the color fades slowly from red to green and so on...